# Custom validation for phone number in JS

Tags: javascript, web, unbounce

I am trying to add phone validation on form submit. 
Main goal is: if phone starts not on "39" or "+39" add this numbers before the number and submit.
Code is added via script manager just after body tag.
But it doesn't work on submit. And I don't have any errors in browser console.

```
<form action="some.php" method="POST">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="lp-pom-form-field single-line-text" id="container_nome">
      <label class="main lp-form-label" for="nome" id="label_nome" style="height: auto;">
        <span class="label-style">Nome e Cognome&nbsp;*</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="" class="ub-input-item single text form_elem_nome">
    </div>
    <div class="lp-pom-form-field single-line-text" id="container_telefono">
      <label class="main lp-form-label" for="telefono" id="label_telefono" style="height: auto;">
        <span class="label-style">Telefono&nbsp;*</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="" class="ub-input-item single text form_elem_telefono">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

 window.onload = function() {
      var mainForm = document.forms[0];
      mainForm.addEventListener("submit", function validPhone() {
        var re = /^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/;
        var myPhone = '';
        var element = document.getElementById('telefono');
        if (element != null) {
          myPhone = element.value;
        }
        else {
          myPhone = null;
        }
        var myPhoneTrim = myPhone.trim().replace(/\s|\-|\(|\)/g, "");
        var valid = re.test(myPhoneTrim);

        if (myPhoneTrim.startsWith("39")) {
          myPhoneTrim = "+" + myPhoneTrim;
        } else if (!myPhoneTrim.startsWith("39") && !myPhoneTrim.startsWith("+39")) {
          myPhoneTrim = "+39" + myPhoneTrim;
        }
        return valid;
      });
    }
```

Comment: have debugged the code in browser? or logged your values in console.

Comment: Add it just after body tag is closed

Comment: @Vega that should be `before` the body tag closed.

Comment: Script added before </body>

Comment: @swetanshkumar Yes, but I cant find out where is the problem

Comment: @Suresh Ponnukalai, yes, I don't know why I typed after.. :)

Comment: @desmond, could you post also an exert of html?

Comment: @Vega html added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your HTML looks like or how you apply the JS script, but running this in JSFiddle seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7u2h3nqn/17/

JS:

```
var mainForm = document.getElementById("lp-pom-button-205");

mainForm.addEventListener("click", function validPhone() {

        var re = /^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/;
        var myPhone = '';
        var element = document.getElementById('telefono');

        if (element != null) {
          myPhone = element.value;
        }
        else {
          myPhone = null;
        }
        var myPhoneTrim = myPhone.trim().replace(/\s|\-|\(|\)/g, "");
        var valid = re.test(myPhoneTrim);

        if (myPhoneTrim.startsWith("39")) {
          myPhoneTrim = "+" + myPhoneTrim;
        } else if (!myPhoneTrim.startsWith("39") && !myPhoneTrim.startsWith("+39")) {
          myPhoneTrim = "+39" + myPhoneTrim;
        }

        console.log(myPhoneTrim);

        return valid;
})
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.
My code is working on JSFiddle and Codepan, even in console.
But doesn't work on unbounce.com LP.
And after all of this - I have no idea why.
Maybe some conflict with unbounce native functionality...

Comment: Not sure about unbounce. Are you sure that you have the correct dom object or the form selected? How are you using it in unbounce?

What if you give the form an ID instead of access by index element?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because this page have only one form.

Comment: Could you share the actual page/url?

Comment: Check the updated example I sent, please. The dom element ORDINA is not a button type="submit".

Comment: Thank you. It works on jsfiddle but still not works on LP.
Tnx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `string.match()`

`var matches = string.match(^39);` instead of `if (myPhoneTrim.startsWith("39"))`

And `var matches = string.match(^[+]39);`

However, I do not see a problem with your initial code. Can you please post the HTML?

Comment: Tnx, I will try .match next time.
HTML added.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. What is exactly wrong though? Are you getting numbers without the `39` or `+39` prefix? Or are you getting no numbers at all?

Comment: Yes, Im getting numbers without the 39 or +39 prefix.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried using `string.match()`? Are sure that the js script is being called? Why don't you try to handle this inside the PHP?

Comment: In JSFiddle script works fine with RegExp search and replace.
And unbounce.com don't give any opportunity to use PHP.

Comment: I have tried it again and it works for me. Maybe try clearing your browser cache?